# Replace string time lyrics or subtitles to data attribute - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

can help me 
or example how to replace string,
if you can use jQuery, so I can easily understand it

### Here's an example

```
<div class="subtitles" id="subtitles">
[00:00.00]text 1
[00:14.71]text 2
[00:43.42]text 3
[00:57.34]text 4
[01:12.00]text 5
[01:29.69]text 6
[01:44.13]text 7
[01:58.05]text 8
[02:12.39]text 9
[02:33.23]text 10
</div>
```

### and the result

```
<div class="subtitles" id="subtitles">
    <p class="sub" data-on="0" data-off="14.71">text 1</p>
    <p class="sub" data-on="14.71" data-off="43.42">text 2</p>
    <p class="sub" data-on="43.42" data-off="57.34">text 3</p>
    <p class="sub" data-on="57.34" data-off="72">text 4</p>
    <p class="sub" data-on="72" data-off="89.69">text 5</p>
    <p class="sub" data-on="89.69" data-off="104.13">text 6</p>
    <p class="sub" data-on="104.13" data-off="118.05">text 7</p>
    <p class="sub" data-on="118.05" data-off="132.39">text 8</p>
    <p class="sub" data-on="132.39" data-off="153.23">text 9</p>
    <p class="sub" data-on="153.23" data-off="Infinity">text 10</p>
</div>
```

Sorry if my english is not good.

thank you if willing to help

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Can you provide it? Is the input a string or the current DOM?

Comment: hi, Your question is not clear enough. Do you want to convert from first (Here's an example) to second(and the result) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `div` is in the current document, you could do it like this:

```js
$('#subtitles').contents().replaceWith(
    $('#subtitles').text()
        .match(/\[.*/gm)
        .map(s => [s.substr(10), +s.substr(4,5) + 60*s.substr(1,2)])
        .map(([text, minutes], i, arr) =>
            $('<p>').addClass('sub')
                .attr('data-on', minutes)
                .attr('data-off', (i+1) in arr ? arr[i+1][1] : 'Infinity')
                .text(text)
        )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subtitles" id="subtitles">
[00:00.00]text 1
[00:14.71]text 2
[00:43.42]text 3
[00:57.34]text 4
[01:12.00]text 5
[01:29.69]text 6
[01:44.13]text 7
[01:58.05]text 8
[02:12.39]text 9
[02:33.23]text 10
</div>
```

Comment: = thank you very much, you really help me.
now i can learn it again